# What is the equivalent of Slater determinants for superconductors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, superconductivity, linear-algebra

Suggestions to better formulate my question are also highly appreciated.

To better explain my question let me start with a very familiar case:

Suppose we have a two-band insulator described by
$$H = \sum_{\boldsymbol k, n} \varepsilon^n(\boldsymbol k)\  d^\dagger_n(\boldsymbol k)d_n (\boldsymbol k), \qquad n \in\{0,1\}, \qquad  \varepsilon^1(\boldsymbol k) > \varepsilon^0(\boldsymbol k).$$
Here $d^\dagger_n(\boldsymbol k) $ creates an electron in the state $|\phi_n(\boldsymbol k)\rangle$.
The ground state of such an insulator $|\Psi\rangle = \prod_k d^\dagger_0(\boldsymbol k) |0\rangle$.
Suppose I have another insulator described by $H' = \sum_{\boldsymbol k, n} \varepsilon'^{n}(\boldsymbol k)\  d'^{\dagger}_{n}(\boldsymbol k)d'_n (\boldsymbol k)$, where $d'^\dagger_n(\boldsymbol k) $ creates an electron in the state $|\phi'_n(\boldsymbol k)\rangle$. The ground state of this primed Hamiltonian is $|\Psi'\rangle = \prod_k d'^\dagger_0(\boldsymbol k) |0\rangle$. The overlap between $|\Psi\rangle$ and $\Psi'\rangle$ is readily given in terms of the single particle wavefunctions as
$$\langle \Psi' | \Psi\rangle  = \det \left[ \langle \phi'_0(\boldsymbol k') | \phi_0(\boldsymbol k)\rangle \right ].$$
This determinant is very efficient to compute, since there is no need to construct the many-body wave functions $|\Psi\rangle$ and $|\Psi' \rangle$.

My question is, suppose we have a similar question for superconductors. If one superconductor is described by
$$H_{BdG} = \sum_{\boldsymbol k, n} \varepsilon^n(\boldsymbol k)\  \gamma^\dagger_n(\boldsymbol k)\gamma_n (\boldsymbol k), \qquad n \in\{0,1\}, \qquad \qquad \varepsilon^1(\boldsymbol k) ,\  \varepsilon^0(\boldsymbol k) > 0, $$
where $\gamma^\dagger_n(\boldsymbol k)$ are the Bogoliubov quasiparticles. The superconducting ground state can be written as $|\Psi_{BdG}\rangle = \prod_k \gamma_1(\boldsymbol k)\gamma_0(\boldsymbol k) |0\rangle$. Considering another superconductor with $H'_{BdG} = \sum_{\boldsymbol k, n} \varepsilon'^n(\boldsymbol k)\  \gamma'^\dagger_n(\boldsymbol k)\gamma'_n (\boldsymbol k)$, and a ground state $|\Psi'_{BdG}\rangle = \prod_k\gamma'_1(\boldsymbol k) \gamma'_0(\boldsymbol k) |0\rangle$, if I ask what is $\langle \Psi'_{BdG} | \Psi_{BdG}\rangle$, is there an efficient way to compute this akin to the Slater determinant for the case of insulators? Given the quadratic nature of the BdG Hamiltonian, it seems that there should be an easy way of doing this, correct?

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is interesting but there is something fishy in the question. In the BdG superconductor if $\gamma$ are the fermions that make the Hamiltonian diagonal, the vacuum (aka ground state) of the Hamiltonian is the state that has no $\gamma^\dagger$ excitations. In other words it is the vacuum for the $\gamma$ operators. If you want to write this state in terms of the old fermions, you get the Thouless form which you wrote in the answer. But this is not what you wrote in the question.

Comment: Another way to put your question would be: scalar product between gaussian states which don't conserve particle number

Comment: @lcv The two forms of the ground state are equivalent. See for example Eqs (10) and (11) in arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02689.pdf

Comment: Ops, yes of course! I mixed up the two vacua. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my answer. Apparently, in the nuclear physics literature, such a formula is known as the 'Onishi' formula. Onishi in quotation because according to Kai Neergård [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.00485.pdf) they never really give proof for it. Anyway as discussed in Neergård talk, if we write the BdG ground state in the Thouless form,
$$ |\Psi_{BdG} \rangle = \exp\left[ \frac{1}{2} C^\dagger F [C^\dagger]^T\right] |0\rangle$$
where $C^\dagger  = [c^\dagger_0, \dots c^\dagger_{n}]$ with $c_i$ are regular electron creation operators and $F = (VU^{-1})^*$. Here $U$ and V are what define the Bogoliubov transformation,
$$\begin{bmatrix}  C \\ [C^\dagger]^T \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  U & V^* \\ V & U^* \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  \Gamma \\ [\Gamma^\dagger]^T \end{bmatrix} $$
The Onishi formula then gives the overlap as
$$\langle \Psi'_{BdG} | \Psi_{BdG} \rangle = (\det[1 + F'^\dagger F])^{1/2} $$.

I can't say I know a way to prove this. However, I'll take solace in that it really doesn't seem trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The analogue of the Slater determinant for BCS is a [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian).  I have a longish account [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588859/fermionic-vacuum-under-a-bogoliubov-transformation/588865#588865).

The usual wavefunction of an  $n$-particle Fock-space state $|{\Psi}\rangle$ is
$$
 \Psi({\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2,\ldots,{\bf r}_n)=
 \langle{0}| {\hat \psi({\bf r}_n)\ldots \hat \psi ({\bf r}_2)\hat\psi ({\bf r}_1)}|{\Psi}\rangle ,
 $$
where
$$
 \hat\psi({\bf r})= \sum_i a_i \psi_i({\bf r})
 $$
is the  field operator and $\langle{0}|$ is the no-particle state.

In the  BCS case   the  unnormalized $2n$-particle-projected  wavefunction
is
$$
\Psi(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{2n})=_a\langle{0}| a_{i_{2n}}\ldots a_{i_1} \exp\left\{\frac 12 a^\dagger_ia^\dagger_jS_{ij}\right\}|{0}\rangle _a\\
={\rm Pf}(S_\sigma), \quad \sigma=\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{2n}\}.\nonumber
$$
Summing over all possible  $2n$-element subsets $\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{2n}\}$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$  and then summing over the particle number $2n$ gives
$$
\langle {S}|{S}\rangle =\sum_{2n=0}^\infty \sum_{\{i_1,\ldots,i_{2n}\}} |\Psi(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{2n})|^2\nonumber\\
= \sum_{\sigma} |{\rm Pf}(S_\sigma)|^2,\nonumber
$$

The normalization factor ${\mathcal N}$ is found from the fermionic version of Major MacMahon's [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacMahon%27s_master_theorem): This asserts  that the inner product of    states of the form
$$
  |{S}\rangle = \exp\left\{\frac 12 a^\dagger_ia^\dagger _jS_{ij}\right\}|0\rangle _a
 $$
is given by
$$
 \langle S_1| S_2\rangle = {\rm det}^{1/2}(I+S^\dagger_1 S_2){=} {\rm Pf}(1+S_1^\dagger S_2)={\rm Pf}(1-S_1^* S_2).
 $$
Here, for skew $S$, $T$, the  ``double Pfaffian'' is
$$
 {\rm Pf}(1-ST)\equiv  \sum_\sigma {\rm Pf}(S_\sigma){\rm Pf}(T_\sigma)
 $$
where $\sigma$ runs though all distinct even-order subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$, including the empty set.   The skew-symmetric  sub-matrix  $S_\sigma$ is assembled  from the rows and columns of $S$ indexed by $\sigma$, and
${\rm Pf}(S_\sigma)$ is the usual Pfaffian

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I hoped I'd be done with my problem and be able to use this expression. Alas, with my problem I have the matrix U have some singular values that require special attention. I'm not sure yet how to address this. I assume one can obtain a truncated form of $U$ using the Bloch-Messiah decomposition, and then use this so calculate $S$. I'm not sure about the details though.